# InvalidArgumentException: Data missing in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\ in Laravel CronJob

Tags: laravel, cron

In my Laravel-5.8 application, I have an api that I ran cron jobs for it:

Model

```
class HrEmployee extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'hr_employees';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'employee_code',
                  'user_id',
                  'email',
                  'drivers_license_expiry_date',
                  'drivers_license_date_of_issue',
                  'hire_date',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'password',
                  'exit_date',
                  'exit_interview_date',
                  'marital_status_id',
                  'username',
                  'department_id',
                  'nav_dept_id',
                  'is_nav_updated',
                  'date_of_birth',
              ];



    protected $appends = ['full_name'];

    protected $dates = [
        'date_of_birth',
        'hire_date',
        'exit_date',
        'exit_interview_date',
        'drivers_license_expiry_date',
        'drivers_license_date_of_issue',
    ];

    protected $casts = [];   

    public function setDateOfBirthAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['date_of_birth'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
    }

    public function getDateOfBirthAttribute($input)
    {
         return $input ? Carbon::parse($input)->format(config('app.date_format')) : 'Unknown';
    }         

    public function setHireDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['hire_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
    }

    public function getHireDateAttribute($input)
    {
           return $input ? Carbon::parse($input)->format(config('app.date_format')) : 'Unknown';
    }                

    public function setExitDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['exit_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
    }

     public function getExitDateAttribute($input)
     {
         return $input ? Carbon::parse($input)->format(config('app.date_format')) : 'Unknown';
     }  

    public function setDriversLicenseExpiryDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['drivers_license_expiry_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
    }

     public function getDriversLicenseExpiryDateAttribute($input)
     {
         return $input ? Carbon::parse($input)->format(config('app.date_format')) : 'Unknown';
     }              
}
```

From the api, staff_id' which is also the employee_code in the HrEmployee model is unique. If it exists, the code updates other fields. If it doesn't exist, it creates everything.

console/commands:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('GET','https://myapps.net/myapp/employees', [
           'query' => ['key' => '33ddfffg']
       ])->getBody();

        DB::beginTransaction();
       try { 

        $clientdatas = json_decode($res->getContents(), true);  

        foreach($clientdatas as $clientdata)
        {
            $payloads = [
                'username'                              => strtok($clientdata['email_company'], '@'),
                'first_name'                            => $clientdata['first_name'],
                'last_name'                             => $clientdata['last_name'],
                'date_of_birth'                         => Carbon::parse($clientdata['date_of_birth'])->format('d-m-Y'),
                'email'                                 => $clientdata['email_company'],
                'line_manager_id'                       => $clientdata['line_manager_id'],
                'drivers_license_expiry_date'           => Carbon::parse($clientdata['drivers_license_expiry_date'])->format('d-m-Y'),
                'hire_date'                             => Carbon::parse($clientdata['hire_date'])->format('d-m-Y'),
                'nationality_code'                      => $clientdata['nationality'],
                'exit_date'                             => Carbon::parse($clientdata['exit_date'])->format('d-m-Y'),
                'exit_interview_date'                   => Carbon::parse($clientdata['exit_interview_date'])->format('d-m-Y'),
                'password'                              => bcrypt("123456"),
                'nav_dept_id'                             => $clientdata['department_id'],
                'dept_code'                             => $clientdata['department_id'],
            ]; 

            if(!isset($clientdata['staff_id'])) { 
               $payloads['nav_dept_id'] = $clientdata['department_id'];
            }     

            $employee = HrEmployee::updateOrCreate([
                        'employee_code' => $clientdata['staff_id'],
                    ], $payloads);       

            //user
            $user = User::updateOrCreate([
                'employee_code'                         => $employee->employee_code,

            ],
            [
                'username'                              => $employee->username,
                'password'                              => bcrypt("123456"),
                'first_name'                            => $employee->first_name,
                'last_name'                             => $employee->last_name,
                'email'                                 => $employee->email,
                'employee_id'                           => $employee->id,
                'name'                                  => $employee->first_name,

            ]);         

             $employee->update(['user_id' => $user->id]);         
        }

           DB::commit();           
            } catch (Exception $exception) {
               Log::error($exception);
                DB::rollback();

            }          

    }
```

I observed that the cron job was not running. When I checked the log, I found this errors:

```
[2020-09-11 01:32:48] production.ERROR: InvalidArgumentException: Data missing in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php:623
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php(645): Carbon\Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '11-09-2020', NULL)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\DateFactory.php(216): Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '11-09-2020')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(239): Illuminate\Support\DateFactory->__call('createFromForma...', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(809): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('createFromForma...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(831): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->asDateTime('11-09-2020')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(576): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->fromDateTime('11-09-2020')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(329): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->setAttribute('exit_interview_...', '11-09-2020')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php(436): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->fill(Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(1124): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}(Object(App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php(437): tap(Object(App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee), Object(Closure))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php(23): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->updateOrCreate(Array, Array)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1618): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), 'updateOrCreate', Array)
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1630): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('updateOrCreate', Array)
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\Console\Commands\UpdateCreateEmployee.php(164): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic('updateOrCreate', Array)
#14 [internal function]: App\Console\Commands\UpdateCreateEmployee->handle()
```

From the api, the dates come in this format:

"date_of_birth": "1964-12-12T00:00:00", while some are null

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: First of all print the output of $payloads and also the error says that you send the value as d-m-Y and carbon expect the format 'Y-m-d H:i:s' i.e createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '11-09-2020')

Answer (score 0):

you may be missing something when passing variable in Carbon::parse(???).. check if your array isset with that index

something like:

```php
$hasDob = isset($clientdata['date_of_birth']);

if ($hasDob) Carbon::parse($clientdata['date_of_birth']);
```

Comment: How do I now relate the above with:    'date_of_birth'                         => Carbon::parse($clientdata['date_of_birth'])->format('d-m-Y'),

Comment: The dates are in this format:  From the api, the dates come in this format:

   "date_of_birth": "1964-12-12T00:00:00",

Comment: while some are null